# Grouping labelled object, not unsupervised clustering: Any method? Hidden markov models?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

Say I have many articles, with the following labels. "classical music","pop music","physics","chemistry". Then an obvious way to group these labelled data is to group the former two under the "music" label and the latter two under "science" label. If my label are not this obvious and there are many of them (so cannot be done manually), is there way of grouping such labels automatically? Is the Hidden markov models relevant for this purpose?

Comment: Your tag 'classification' is the right search term for this problem. Try searching; multinomial logistic regression, linear discriminants, support vector machines.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but I believe those are not what I want. Those are used to classify data with unknown labels when you have a set of data with known labels for learning. However what I need is a way to group the currently available labels somehow.

Comment: As above, but get probabilistic predictions. That is vectors of label membership probabilities for each observed document. Then use something like k-means on the probability vectors to further summarise? How to choose the higher level label automatically will likely be an issue for you I suspect.

Comment: Also, HMMs are for time series data generally.